# Convince a territorial pup to go out on walks

Tags: dogs, behavior, strays, territory

I recently adopted a stray pup. Although it is great in most ways, I just can't convince it to go out on short walks. It thinks the area around the house is its territory and is very happy/playful there, but once I cross its perceived "borders" it just sniffs the bushes/shrubbery other strays might have urinated on and sits down every 20 feet (a few meters) or so, and moves a bit only after much coaxing. Once we turn back to head home, the mood completely changes and he's again full of energy. It is still a pup, around 4 months old I think (can't be sure because when I picked it up, it was sickly and abandoned on the street).